# Laravel search functionality

Tags: laravel

I've got a searchbar on my homepage which looks like this:

```
                <form action="{{ route('search', $query) }}" method="GET" role="search">
                <div class="input-group mb-4 search_bar">
                    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-describedby="button-addon5" class="form-control search_input">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="button-addon5" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

My route looks like this:

```
Route::get('all-{query}-posts', 'SearchController@index')->where('query', '[A-Za-z0-9-]+')->name('search');
```

So basically I want the input of the searchbar in my url like this: /all-stuff-posts instead of the usual: ?search=stuff
It seems to automatically add the ?search=stuff to the end even though I didn't add that anywhere so that's the first problem.

The second problem is that I can only retrieve the query in the controller but that gives me an error in web.php because the query is still not set. Is there a different way of doing this that does work?

Comment: because you are using method="GET" within the form

Comment: You need use post data when you are using search function. And let us what's wrong in your codes?

Comment: I solved the first problem by using POST as a method, but the second problem is still there. The $query is empty in my route because I can only get the query in my controller.

Comment: If I understand you, I answered. If you look at the answer, you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form action method below like this

```
<form action="{{url('')}}/all-{{$query}}-posts" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used Post method.

```
<form action="{{ route('search', $query) }}" method="POST" role="search">
```

Comment: I solved the first problem by using POST as a method, but the second problem is still there. The $query is empty in my route because I can only get the query in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a search engine in your app, I will suggest the following. (One of the simplest ways).
Learn about POST, GET, PUT first.\
Then, My model like this

```
 public function scopeSearchByKeyword($query, $keyword,$location)
{
    if ($keyword!='' and $location!='') {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword,$location) {
        $query->where("title", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
                ->where("location_id", "$location")
                ->where("status", "1");                     
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where("title", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
            ->where("status", "1");
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Here I am searching by title and location. It can output even if only a keyword is entered.
Then my controller like this:

```
public function search_kasblar(Request $request)    
{ 
   $inputs = $request->all();
   $keyword = $inputs['search_keyword'];
   $location = $inputs['location'];

   $jobs= JobBoards::SearchByKeyword($keyword,$location)->get();
   $total_res=count($jobs);  
    return view('jobs.search',compact('jobs','total_res','keyword'));
}
```

Here we can search for incoming data in the input.
So my view blade like this:

```
<div class="finderform">
        {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'listings/search','class'=>'','id'=>'search','role'=>'form')) !!}
          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 no-padding"> <i class="fa fa-search local-search-ic"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search_keyword" id="input-search-term" title="Search for..." placeholder="Search anything here" value="" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-sm-5 no-padding"> <i class="fa fa-map-marker local-search-ic ic-map-location"></i>                        
      <div class="">
      <select id="location" name="location" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Location</option>
        @foreach(\App\Location::orderBy('location_name')->get() as $location) 
        <option value="{{$location->id}}">{{$location->location_name}}</option> 
        @endforeach

      </select>
      </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn tp-btn-default tp-btn-lg">Search</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

You can use like this.
And use POST in your router...